# How to make tokenUrl configurable

Tags: openapi

Is there anyway to make the token url in OpenAPI spec configurable.

For instance the I want to make the realm `{{REALM_NAME_HERE}}` below configurable from swagger UI.

```
  securitySchemes:

    oauth:
      type: oauth2
      description: This API uses OAuth 2
      flows:
        clientCredentials:
          tokenUrl: http://localhost:32777/auth/realms/{{REALM_NAME}}/protocol/openid-connect/token
          scopes: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

`tokenUrl` does not support variables. There's a corresponding feature request in the OpenAPI Specification repository:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/551

However, if the parameterized part of the `tokenUrl` (in your example - `http://localhost:32777/auth/realms/{{REALM_NAME}}`) also happens to be the API server URL, you can define `tokenUrl` relative to the server URL:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0

servers:
  - url: 'http://localhost:32777/auth/realms/{REALM_NAME}'
    variables:
      REALM_NAME:
        default: some_default_realm   # default value is required

paths:
  ...

components:
  securitySchemes:
    oauth:
      type: oauth2
      description: This API uses OAuth 2
      flows:
        clientCredentials:
          tokenUrl: './protocol/openid-connect/token'
          scopes: {}
```

Comment: Thanks the server option isn't a runner for me. So looks like I could be waiting a while for this JIRA

Comment: Also, at least in swagger UI the parameterized servers url approach you described doesn't work. It doesn't substitute the `{REALM_NAME}`

Comment: Looks like a known issue with Swagger UI: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4740